# Jacoco Jenkins plugin working but maven report showing 0% coverage

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco

I am wanting to collect coverage metrics with JaCoCo for Restassured based integration tests running against an external JVM process all orchestrated in Maven 3.

I have the following setup:

1. The pre-integration-test phase exec's the java process via ant to fork it off in it's own process, passing the jacoco agent arg
2. The post-integration-test phase exec's a script that kills the pid of that process
3. jacoco's javaco-it.exec file is found in the target directory the end of the mvn run but the html report shows 0% coverage  (Sessions show all the classes that it collected.)
4. When run in Jenkins with the Jacoco plugin, the reports there look fine.

I see many people asking similar questions here and around the web, but most are using Sonar and their solutions all seem to be Sonar-centric.  I am really needing the maven plugin version (sans-Sonar) to work.

Here is the pertinent portion of my pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>com.mydomain.*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <classDumpDir>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it-classes</classDumpDir>
                        <propertyName>jacocoArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>METHOD</element>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <java fork="true" classpathref="maven.runtime.classpath"
                                  className="com.mydomain.MainApp" spawn="true">
                                <jvmarg value="${jacocoArgLine}"/>
                            </java>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>kill-app</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>bash</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>killApp.sh</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When run via "mvn clean install" I see the following in the output:

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:report (default-report) @ integration-tests ---
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'integration-tests' with 0 classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.1.201405082137:report-integration (default-report-integration) @ integration-tests ---
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'integration-tests' with 0 classes
```

One thing to note: I am having to use the classDumpDir since there are jar dependencies in the VM that I want coverage stat's from that aren't part of this Maven project.   Is there some setting I'm not seeing in the doc's to tell the reporting goal about that class dir?

Answer (score 0):

My solution: do not run jacoco outside maven. Run it together and configure the colect data like these:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>com/quantaconsultoria/**/*</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>br/com/infotec/**/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>br/com/taxisimples/**/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>com/cocento/**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-unit-test</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The goal report and phase (verify and prepare-package) will collect all data and write appropriate report.